# Java JLabel dynamic name settings / name reference

Tags: java, jlabel

I am able to read in the values from the file of .properties and I am able to transfer those values to a method that generates `JLabels` automatically. 
After this step I should have been able to rename the `JLabel` with `name.setName()` command.
My problem is that I am not able to reference to the proper `JLabel` names.

I used this source code:

This is the code for `JLabel` generation:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < Read.ipList.size(); i++){
  Middlepanel.add(new JLabel("" + Read.ipList.get(i)));
}`
```

I use this method to rename the `JLabel` but this method doesn't work:

```java
for (i = 0; i < Read.ipList.size(); i++){           
  Read.ipList.get(i).setName("newname"));
}
```

Comment: if you want to set the **text** displayed by the `JLabel`, use `setText`. `setName` will change the name of the `JLabel` (every component has a name)

Comment: Text in ALL CAPS == shounting. Please don't shout.

Comment: Read.ipList doesn't contain your JLabels, how do you expect it to work? Either you get them from Middlepanel or you use another container to keep them

Comment: The JLables are added to MiddlePanel ( named against the naming conventions) not to your list `ipList`. Anyway why are you using `setName` and what do you expect to do?